# Get MIME content of multiple messages using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: mime, outlook-restapi, outlook-api, microsoft-graph-api

It is well documented that you can use the MS Graph API to get the MIME content of a *single* message by appending `$value` to the query.

However, I am using the `/messages` endpoint with a search to grab a bunch of messages at once and I would like the MIME content returned for each of them without having to iterate individually and make more calls. My attempts to add the `$value` param have not been working so far. I'm doing something like this:

```
/me/messages?$value&$search=from:email@domain.com
```

Am I doing this wrong or is this just not supported?

Answer (score 0):

URL segment `$value` can be added only when accessing a single item.

`$value` cannot be applied to a collection.

Resources:

[OData URL capabilities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#other-odata-url-capabilities)

[Requesting an Individual Property Raw Value](https://www.odata.org/getting-started/basic-tutorial/#propertyVal)

Comment: Thanks, is this documented?

Comment: @Danny I've updated the answer and added links to documentation